# Sorting large number of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling a large number of nodes from sharepoint list and I'll try to sort them into a html table hopefully in orderly fashion. The way i need to do this is I need to split these z:rows into 5 different tables. Example should be self explanatory: [`https://jsfiddle.net/jse21z9d/1/`](https://jsfiddle.net/jse21z9d/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#execB').click(function(){
        $('.myUl li').each(function(){

            var liText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var newliText = liText.replace(/[{()}]/g, "");
            var textArray = newliText.split(/[,]/);
            console.log(textArray);

            $(textArray).each(function(index){
                    switch(true){
                        case (textArray[index].indexOf('pol') != -1):
                            $('#polDiv').append(liText+"<br>");
                            break;    
                        case (textArray[index].indexOf('uk') != -1)
                                    || (textArray[index].indexOf('ire') != -1):   
                            $('#ukDiv').append(liText+"<br>");
                            break;
                        case (textArray[index].indexOf('ger') != -1):
                            $('#gerDiv').append(liText+"<br>");
                            break;
                        case (textArray[index].indexOf('san') != -1):
                            $('#sanDiv').append(liText+"<br>");
                            break;        
                    }

            });
        });

    });
});
```

so that's what i got so far, and I'm wondering maybe there is a better way to do this as I think this code I wrote might slow the entire load up a lot if we are talking about 1000+ z:rows(li in this case) to go through?

Comment: Rewriting this in vanilla javascript would technically be faster since you'd be removing the bulky jquery overhead. Also have you tested this code for your 1000+ entries? It may be fast enough with that volume

Comment: Using JS for processing a large number of elements is not a good idea. It's better that you use basic JavaScript.

Comment: I haven't tested this particular code so far. I have tested a code that pulls the data and throws it into a particular table. The only problem is that the other code i tested it on does not take into consideration that a topic might belong to another section as well. For instance if it says uk/ire, pol it will just throw this topic to UK/IRE tab instead of UK/IRE and POL at the same time. It seems to already be taking it's time on this code not to mention if i add the above array.split();

Comment: pull the elements out of the dom and sort there, then replace all at once instead of using `append()` for each one. Your individual appends in the dom rather than outside it are not very efficient

Comment: sorry Sir I'm quite newb to programming I'm just learning I don't think i followed - charlietfl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your own code with the following:
- Less appends: The iterations generate a string instead of multiple appends thus less actions are done over the DOM.
- Less searches: Even though a search by ID is generally an easy search. Its still better to execute the it once, and append the generated string.

Source:
https://jsfiddle.net/mamtkjw4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('#execB').click(function(){
        
         var polStr = "";
            var ukStr = "";
            var gerStr = "";
            var sanStr = "";
        
            $('.myUl li').each(function(){
                
                var liText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var newliText = liText.replace(/[{()}]/g, "");
                var textArray = newliText.split(/[,]/);
                console.log(textArray);

                $(textArray).each(function(index){
                        switch(true){
                            case (textArray[index].indexOf('pol') != -1):
                              polStr = polStr + liText+"<br>";
                                break;    
                            case (textArray[index].indexOf('uk') != -1)
                               || (textArray[index].indexOf('ire') != -1):   
                              ukStr = ukStr + liText+"<br>";
                                break;
                            case (textArray[index].indexOf('ger') != -1):
                              gerStr = gerStr + liText+"<br>";
                                break;
                            case (textArray[index].indexOf('san') != -1):
                              sanStr = sanStr + liText+"<br>";
                                break;        
                        }
                    
                });
            });
            
            
          if (polStr) {
             $('#polDiv').append(polStr+"<br>");
            } 
            
            if (ukStr) {
             $('#ukDiv').append(ukStr+"<br>");
            } 
            
            if (gerStr) {
             $('#gerDiv').append(gerStr+"<br>");
            } 
            
            if (sanStr) {
             $('#sanDiv').append(sanStr+"<br>");
            } 
            
            
        });
    });
```

```css
    .holders{
        
        background: gray;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<button id="execB">execB</button>
 <ul class="myUl">
        <li>(UK/IRE, POL)</li>
        <li>(UK/IRE)</li>
        <li>(POL)</li>
        <li>(SAN)</li>
        <li>(GER, POL)</li>
        <li>(GER)</li>
        <li>(SAN, UK/IRE)</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="gerDiv" class="holders"><p>german div:</p><ul></ul></div>
    <div id="ukDiv" class="holders"><p>uk/ire div:</p><ul></ul></div>
    <div id="polDiv" class="holders"><p>pol div:</p><ul></ul></div>
    <div id="sanDiv" class="holders"><p>san div:</p><ul></ul></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'll test it out once i get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as short and sweet as it gets. Also, this will multiply your text entry every time you click, so you can see how it handles as it gets *larger*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var clickCount = 1;
 $("#execB").on("click", function() {
  clickCount++;
      $(this).text("Count("+clickCount+")");
  $(".myUl li").each(function() {
   var liText = new Array(clickCount).join($(this).text().toLowerCase() + "\n"),
    textArray = liText.replace(/[{()}]/g, "").split(/[,]/);
   $(textArray).each(function(i) {
    switch (!0) {
     case -1 != textArray[i].indexOf("pol"):
      $("#polDiv").append(liText + "<br>");
      break;
     case -1 != textArray[i].indexOf("uk") || -1 != textArray[i].indexOf("ire"):
      $("#ukDiv").append(liText + "<br>");
      break;
     case -1 != textArray[i].indexOf("ger"):
      $("#gerDiv").append(liText + "<br>");
      break;
     case -1 != textArray[i].indexOf("san"):
      $("#sanDiv").append(liText + "<br>")
    }
   });
  });
  $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
 })
});
```

```css
.holders{
 background: gray;
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 float: left;
}
button { position: fixed; top: .6em; }
ul { margin-top: 2.25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="execB">execB</button>
<ul class="myUl">
 <li>(UK/IRE, POL)</li>
 <li>(UK/IRE)</li>
 <li>(POL)</li>
 <li>(SAN)</li>
 <li>(GER, POL)</li>
 <li>(GER)</li>
 <li>(SAN, UK/IRE)</li>
</ul>
<div id="gerDiv" class="holders"><p>german div:</p><ul></ul></div>
<div id="ukDiv" class="holders"><p>uk/ire div:</p><ul></ul></div>
<div id="polDiv" class="holders"><p>pol div:</p><ul></ul></div>
<div id="sanDiv" class="holders"><p>san div:</p><ul></ul></div>
```

Also it will auto scroll so you can just keep pushing the button ...

If it helps any, on system I'm currently on [HP ProBook 650 G1 Win7 Pro64], in Chrome, it didn't start slowing down till count of clicks on button was around 100, on FF around 95 and on IE Edge, also around 100. That would be that `ul` text 100 *times*